Old movie about a young boy crossing a border into America to find a relative
I watched this in the nineties when I was about eight years old. I am almost certain it was showing on TNT.
It was black and white (as far as I can remember) and about a young boy crossing a border into America to find a relative (an aunt or uncle) he has never met. When he reaches the border he is unable to cross and spend the night in a wrecked car. He makes preparations to cross the desert despite warnings that after a day he will be as wrinkled as a prune.
When he needs water he takes a hose he has brought with him and uses it to whack a cactus till it breaks open and he drinks from the cactus flesh. He also encounters a snake in a rocky ravine and almost gets bitten.
Eventually he makes his way to his relative and asks to be taken care of but is shunned. When he goes to leave down the garden path the relative takes pity and changes their mind.
That's about all I can recall but it made an impression on me!

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
